If $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$ is Diophantine?
Is $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$ Diophantine?
Which means does $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$ have the property: exist $\tau,\gamma>0, $ for $\forall p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$
$$\left|p-q\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\right|\geq\frac{\gamma}{|q|^\tau}.$$
Generally I need to find a rational series that converges to $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$ to estimate the approximation error.
I searched a series that is maybe helpful:
$$\sqrt{\pi}=2\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}\left(\sum_{r=0}^k\frac{(-1)^r}{(2r)!(k-r)!}\frac{d^{2r}}{dx^{2r}}\left(\left.\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-e^{-x^2}}}\right)^{2k+1}\right|_{x\to0}\right).$$ But I can't estimate the order of term in rational number.

Your number is transcendental so it must have an irrationality measure more than 2.

I know, my problem is to get a supper bound for $\tau$. Namely it isn't a Liouville number

Do the diophantine properties of $\sqrt{2/\pi}$ follow from the diophantine properties of $\pi$?

How do you feel about applying the binomial theorem to $$\left(1+\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-1\right)\right)^{-1/2}  \text{?}$$  The power series is alternating and $\pi/2 - 1 \in [1/2,3/5]$, so doesn't vanish too slowly.

Is it essential that you work with series? Quite often, questions regarding how well you can approximate with rational numbers are investigated with the help of continued fractions.

I just thought of a method like the proof of Liouville theorem, please help me check if there are any questions.
Take $f(x)=\pi x^2-2$, has $\alpha=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$ as its root. We can use the mean value theorem:
Take the rational value $\frac{p}{q}\in[\alpha-1,\alpha+1]$, then there exists $\xi$ on this interval and a positive real $M$  such that
$$\left\lvert\frac{f \left(\frac{p}{q}\right)-f(\alpha)}{\frac{p}{q}-\alpha}\right\rvert= |f'(\xi)|\leq M$$
then $$\left\lvert\frac{p}{q}-\alpha\right\rvert\geq\frac{1}{M}\left\lvert\pi\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^2-2\right\rvert\geq\frac{1}{Mq^{16}}$$
the last inequality was found in the answer of from Julián Aguirre in sequence of diophantine approximants of $\pi$:
So we have
$$\left\lvert p-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}q\right\rvert\geq\frac{1}{Mq^{15}}.$$

I edited the post but only did an ok improving it. You definitely should introduce $\xi$ but that sentence has to many "In/on this interval." It deserves a rewrite.

I messed with your answer a little bit for readability. Feel free to roll it back or do whatever you want to do. :)
So if I'm reading this correctly, you are saying that we have a proof that the upper bound for $\sqrt{2/\pi}$ is less than 15?

I am not sure how we are getting from your linked answer to your conclusion but I will keep on fiddling with this.
